# How do I select vertices that are directly under the other?

Tags: vertices, selection-tools

I'd like to select vertices that are directly beneath the one I am selecting to save me the trouble from moving out of ortho view. It's mostly on simple shapes like the cube below.

Notice how the first image has two vertices selected. However, if the other side is not.

[N http://puu.sh/kg0oN/a618eee709.png](http://puu.sh/kg0oN/a618eee709.png)

I want to be able to select vertices like so without coming out of ortho mode:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In edit mode disable Limit Selection to Visible.

Comment: the best solution to this problem is the border occlusion addon - [download it here](https://github.com/Darcvizer/Border-Occlusion) [video how its works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RwrHI2Tj90)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In edit mode disable Limit **Selection to Visible**.

[image]

An alternative approach is to switch to **Wireframe Mode** with the <kbd>Z</kbd> key.

[image]

## Blender 2.8

In 2.8, these tools have changed location:

[image: location of beforementioned icons in 2.8]

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work for me for some reason.

Comment: After toggling the Limit Selection to Visible button, right-click the first vertex, then hold shift and right-click again (on that same vertex) and the vertex directly behind it will ALSO be selected. It works. Try it.

Comment: That does work. But I was more looking for doing it in one click? Kinda like what B does, but with clicking instead? Or is that not a thing, haha

Comment: @EricPatton Instead of using B , press C (Circle Select) and just click on the vertice once.

Answer (score 35):

## Blender 2.8

You must enable X-Ray.

[image: x-ray mode screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I just switch to wireframe mode. `z` => `4`.