# How do I only select vertices which are visible from my perspective in 3D View?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, selection-tools, geometry, select

I'm trying to retopologize a high poly mesh and create a low poly version out of the existing sculpt. While selecting some vertices of my low poly mesh in order to edit them, other non-visible vertices are always getting selected automatically, which is tedious to work with:

[image]

**Q:** How do I only select the vertices which are visible from my perspective in 3D View?

Higher Resolution video showing the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DduJe.jpg

Comment: Should work by default, make sure x-ray is turned off: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43890/31447 However I also noticed some inconsistent behavior while testing it. If that doesn't work, consider to file a bug report. Good luck. (removed my comments btw)

Comment: I was afraid so myself from suspicion because I have tested it on other mesh, and yes, in the clip I toggle xray and wireframe but I know it happens in a shorter time span :) Thanks for the help sir it is a shame of this glitch luckily I am trained to hide and unhide mesh with custom hotkeys lol.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated: **The issue still happens, less often but it still happens.****

I was able to solve the issue by changing the "display as" "wire" to "textured" under the view-port display under object properties.

[image]
[image]