# How to restrict vertex selection only to those visible within camera cut-off range?

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

I'm trying to do some NURBS editing. I want it to match some reference images set 5μm apart. I set a camera cut-offs to give me 4μm slice.

Is there a way to restrict edit-mode selection to visible vertices only? Whenever I drag a selection box in the main area (front view along Y axis), the selection includes vertices in the back way past camera cut-off (shown in left bottom area) as can be seen on left top area with a side view facing X axis. (Ignore out of plane vertices as I was dumb to use Proportional Editing without plane restriction. That is why it looks messy).

[I see](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43886/why-wont-lasso-or-box-select-select-all-of-the-faces-in-the-region/43890#43890) [many](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38808/how-do-i-select-vertices-that-are-directly-under-the-other) similar questions that mention unchecking x-ray. It does not affect this behavior. I tried all types of Viewport Shading w/ and w/o Toggle X-Ray.

If I remove reference images object from view, I do see only vertices that are within camera cut-off distance only. Yet selection includes stuff in the back... but not in the front. I don't think I found a bug. Did I? What am I missing?

[image: Vertex selection ignores camera cut-off]